# Why does GNU tar --format=pax produce ustar archives?

Tags: posix, tar, archive

I'm using GNU `tar` (v1.29) to create an archive and `xxd` to inspect it like this:

```
(
    cd "$(mktemp -d)"
    touch -d@0 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
    tar \
        --format=pax \
        --numeric-owner \
        --owner=0 \
        --group=0 \
        --pax-option="exthdr.name=%d/PaxHeaders.0/%f,delete=atime,delete=ctime" \
        --mtime=@0 \
        -cf ../123.tar \
        1.txt 2.txt 3.txt
    xxd ../123.tar | grep -C1 ustar
    rm -rf $PWD
)
```

Which gives me this:

```
000000f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000100: 0075 7374 6172 0030 3000 0000 0000 0000  .ustar.00.......
00000110: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
--
000002f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000300: 0075 7374 6172 0030 3000 0000 0000 0000  .ustar.00.......
00000310: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
--
000004f0: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
00000500: 0075 7374 6172 0030 3000 0000 0000 0000  .ustar.00.......
00000510: 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000  ................
```

Why does `tar --format=pax` produce an archive with `ustar` in it?

Comment: `pax` is a superset of `ustar`. That's why. I've made a technical comparison of tar archive formats here:
https://serverfault.com/a/897948

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pax Interchange Format](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/pax.html#tag_20_92_13_01):

> A pax archive tape or file produced in the -x pax format shall contain
> a series of blocks. The physical layout of the archive shall be
> identical to the ustar format described in ustar Interchange Format.

"ustar" followed by 1 zero/NUL byte is the value of the `magic` field indicating the type of the archive:

> The `magic` field is the specification that this archive was output in
> this archive format. If this field contains **ustar** (the five
> characters from the ISO/IEC 646:1991 standard IRV shown followed by
> NUL), …

Of course, that's only for any conforming `pax` utility, but I'd expect `pax` format archives created by GNU `tar` to create archives in the same way as a conforming `pax` implementation.